# InfluxDB - ExceptionPKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool, influxdb-2

We are trying to use a self-signed certificate to update data to an influx db over TLS.

I  can log into the Influx console with https by by adding these parameters to the xml for the service:

```
--tls-cert "certs/cert.crt"
--tls-key "certs/cert.key"
```

However, I get this exception when I try to write to it from the Java process:

```
15:59:44.438 [DACQ-DEBUG-Status-logging] ERROR c.i.client.InfluxDBClientFactory - Influx ExceptionPKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

There are a lot of links with this error, but so far none of the solutions I've tried have worked.

Note: I added the certificate to cacert with this command:

```
keytool -import -alias influxdbcert -file cacert.crt -keystore "C:\Program Files\MyCompany\Analytics Solutions\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Also it is showing up in the cacert with this command:

```
>keytool -list -keystore cacerts | findstr influx
influxdbcert, Apr 19, 2023, trustedCertEntry,
```

Any ideas? I've used keytool before and it usually works. It seems as if the cert has been added, and I can access the console using https when the parameters are added to the service. It's just that the Java process doesn't seem to find it, nor through the service nor the cacert.

This is on Java 17 with Windows 10.